# Is it possible to enable gift messages for virtual products?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onestepcheckout, messages, ce-1.9.2.4

I'm using the one step checkout extension on my Magento store and enabled the gift message option however I noticed that this only works for "shippable" products, if the items are virtual then the gift message doesn't come through in the order page even though it shows in the frontend and let's you fill up the text fields.

I guess there must be a check in the core that skips it if the product can't be shipped, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what is your magento version??

Comment: The latest one 1.9.2.4